# Python script not being interpreted

Tags: python

I'm very new to Python, seriously, painful newb question here.
Uploaded **domainname.com/test.py** to server containing nothing but:

```
    #output data

import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect("company.db")

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM employee") 
print("fetchall:")
result = cursor.fetchall() 
for r in result:
    print(r)
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM employee") 
print("\nfetch one:")
res = cursor.fetchone() 
print(res)
```

it's literally just displaying output

```
 #output data

import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect("company.db")

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM employee") 
print("fetchall:")
result = cursor.fetchall() 
for r in result:
    print(r)
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM employee") 
print("\nfetch one:")
res = cursor.fetchone() 
print(res)
```

in PHP or ASP I would use  <% %> - feel like I'm missing something obvious here. Obviously in PHP I would easily output this to the screen - I can't seem to find a basic explanation of how to do this in python.

I tried **domainname.com/test.cgi** moved it to various folders etc still nothing.

I'm using a Linux Operating System. It recommends PYTHON 2.7 which is enabled. I'm just using Sublime Text editor. I do have latest Python 3.8 on my machine presumably this simple code should still work.

What am I missing to enable Python to run server side.

Comment: This might be better asked at https://serverfault.com/ since it seems to be a web server configuration issue.

Comment: You can't use HTML tags to do anything with Python stdout. Why would you want to? If you want it to be displayed on a web page, you should look into web frameworks like django or flask

Comment: I don't think this should be asked on serverfault. It seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding in what `print` will do

Comment: I've updated my question. to make more sense.

Comment: I don't see what it's clarified. And you just repeated the same code block twice?

Comment: Well the script is not being interpreted by the server and print is probably the wrong way to out the variable.

Comment: You need to invoke the python interpreter. `python test.py` or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this script did not execute was that the shared hosting server (once activated as python was not installed by default) took a while to switch over to supporting (installing) python scripts, during this period the script did not appear run properly. The script above now runs.

Answer (score 0):

Add the shebang, with the Python interpreter location, at the first line of the file, for example:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

print('Ciao')
# Other code....
```

The interpreter could be installed in different locations depending on the server configuration, in my example was /usr/local/bin/python

Comment: @roganjosh yes, the output is the file because the script is not being interpreted, this usually happens where there is not the shebang

Comment: So the OP is not passing the file to the interpreter? Oh, my bad

Comment: @roganjosh with CGI scripts you just "visit" the file via browser, for example: domainname.com/test.py, like PHP. The file is interpreted and executed after the request but a Python CGI script must indicate the interpreter location

Comment: Is that enough to make this work? It's going to print out in a browser?

Comment: I just tried it and it did not work. The hosts recommendation:  https://help.fasthosts.co.uk/app/answers/detail/a_id/567/kw/scripting%20path/session/L3RpbWUvMTU3Njk2OTk5OS9nZW4vMTU3Njk2OTk5OS9zaWQvZlVMWGtpQ1JrdVh1UiU3RVZ4TlZycnR4UFBQczMwTEJkcXp5b3VqenZ0ViU3RUxGJTdFekgxa3JuZGglN0U3REtBOEtrVWlIYktHOCU3RUZ6NzZfUElEb0lTQVZsOThVNFVyV3p2S2dZMmxrWXhTckN0aTV2SkVXV1FBY0xzUzlGZyUyMSUyMQ==

Comment: @roganjosh If you are using a classic hosting provider where you just upload the files, so the web server (Apache or Nginx usually) is already configured, yes. Note that the hosting provider should support CGI script (but I never seen an hosting provider that doesn't support CGI scripts)

Comment: This is my exact output:#!/usr/bin/python

import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect("company.db")

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM employee") 
print("fetchall:")
result = cursor.fetchall() 
for r in result:
    print(r)
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM employee") 
print("\nfetch one:")
res = cursor.fetchone() 
print(res)

Comment: I just added:  #!/usr/bin/python

Comment: Do you have uploaded your file under the cgi-bin folder? So visit domainname.com/cgi-bin/test.py. This should work

Comment: There is a htdocs folder which I've run the script in and then inside that a folder called: webapp which has: public and: tmp folder. Tried all 3 with the above script and does not work. (there is no specific folder called "cgi-bin"

Comment: e.g. I get:Not Found
The requested URL domains.com/webapp/sql-output.py was not found on this server.

Comment: you must use the cgi-script folder (see their guide: https://help.fasthosts.co.uk/app/answers/detail/a_id/34/~/where-to-upload-your-website-files). If there isn't try to create it yourself

Comment: I have done this and set permissions. tried both .py and .cgi had the following error: Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at admin@domains123.uk to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: ok, it seems to work, see the error.log file for find what the error is

Comment: There is only logfile output: last is: [22/Dec/2019:00:02:04 +0000] "GET /cgi-bin/sql-output.py HTTP/1.1" 500 533 "-" "Mozilla/5.0